# $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(2+h)^3 - 8}{h} = + \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

Does this computation correct?
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(2+h)^3 - 8}{h} = + \infty$$

Comment: You did not show your calculation. The answer is not correct.

Comment: Oh. So the limit does not exist, right...?

Comment: The limit does exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\dfrac{(2+h)^{3}-8}{h}=\dfrac{8+12h+6h^{2}+h^{3}-8}{h}=12+6h+h^{2}$

Letting $h$ tend to $0$ we get 12. If you are familiar with derivatives this limit represents the derivative of $f(x)=x^{3}$ at $x=2$.